# What does "resolve away" exactly mean in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have never had logic classes so I always struggle with the assignments that concern this interesting field.
I was reading the slides about resolution theorem proving and there was a step-by-step explanation of how to prove the following example:

[image]

After several steps the result was the following:

[image]

After reading through the complete proof I understood that I do not understand the meaning of "resolve" in *"By resolving away Q in lines 5 and 7, we get R"*. I know it is a very trivial question, but what does "resolve away" literally mean?

Comment: have you checked the resolution proof rule on wikipedia?

Comment: You can see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041803/resolution-on-set-of-clauses).

Comment: And also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959276/direct-proof-logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to think about it colloquially: $\neg Q\vee R$ is a *problem* - does $\neg Q$ hold or does $R$ hold? - and the hypothesis $Q$ *resolves* the problem, resulting in a formula ("$R$") not containing $Q$.

Technically, this is an example of "resolution": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_inference. The notation is a bit weird, but what's going on is this:

- $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas, and we think of $\Gamma$ as being the *disjunction* of those formulas. So, for example, $\{P, Q, R\}$ means $P\vee Q\vee R$. If $\Gamma\subset\Gamma'$ then $\Gamma'$ is *weaker* than $\Gamma$.
- In particular, "$\Gamma\cup\{\varphi\}$" means "One of the statements in $\Gamma$ is true, *or* $\varphi$ is true.
- If $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, \Gamma_3$ are sets of formulas, then $${\Gamma_1 \quad \Gamma_2 \over \Gamma_3}$$ means "from $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ we can deduce $\Gamma_3$."
- The "$\vert l \vert$" off to the side is just a bookkeeping device.

NOTE: there are many different ways to present formal proofs; I find the one in the wikipedia page I cited very unusual. The two (or three) column proof method you use is much simpler, albeit annoyingly long and sometimes hard to read; *natural deduction* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction strikes a nice balance.

Comment: Is there any specific intuition behind when to apply resolution to 1,2 2,4 3,4...? It looks pretty random to me.

Comment: Well, you just look for places where resolution could occur - that is, times when you have statements of the form "$A\vee . . .$" and "$\neg A\vee . . . $". Basically, it's always a good idea to resolve when you can.

Comment: By the way, the proof can be recast as a proof by cases (on $P\vee Q$ - in the $P$ case, use resolution on $P, \neg P\vee R$ and similarly in the $Q$ case). I think in general it makes things easier to understand if we avoid unnecessary proof by contradiction, and there are even philosophical/mathematical reasons to do so.